# Time complexity of this implementation of counting sort

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have to determine the time complexity for the given code of counting sort. I know that counting sort should be O(n+k) but I just can't see how this function is O(n+k), seeing as there is a for loop inside the second for loop.

```py
def counting_sort(array, k): # k is max(array)

    count = (k+1) * [0]  
    sorted = []
    for i in array:
        count[i] += 1
    for i in range(len(count)):
        if count[i] != 0:
            sorted += [i for j in range(count[i])]
    return sorted
```

Wouldn't the worst case be n+k^2, if the elements are unique?

Comment: The inner loop (comprehension) increases your complexity from k to n because it expands the non-singular elements

Comment: No, because the inner loop only loops `count[i]` times, not `k` times.

Comment: SUM(count[i]) == len(array)

Comment: If there's only a single repeating element, the inner loop would only execute once. In the end, your loops are always performing "add an element to the array" exactly `n` times.

Comment: @Blorgbeard would that mean that worst case is n+k, or 2n?

Comment: n+k, because the first loop runs `k` times.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I think you mixed up n and k, the first for loop runs n times since there are n elements. If i understood your previous explanation correctly the second loop runs a maximum of k times, since if count[i] = 0, it doesnt add an element and doesnt count as an operation correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first loop

```py
for i in array:
    count[i] += 1
```

takes n iterations, for the second loop  the number of instructions 
executed in the worst case scenario for the list comprehension:

```
i for j in range(count[i]) #
```

is `count[i]`, and the sum of all `count[i]` is equal to n. 
Note that the comparison

```
        if count[i] != 0:
```

is done k times, and in the worst case scenario the

```
sorted +=...
```

is also done k-times. Adding all this up you get your O(n+k)

(assuming the += for `sorted` is constant cost, otherwise we have to say that the += is amortized constant and so the result comes with that caveat).

Comment: So the list comprehension will run max n times, with the comparison running k times, wouldnt that make it n*k?

Comment: No,  because the list comprehension cannot run n times for every k. the total sum of list comprehension iterations is equal to the sum of count[i] which is exactly n.

Comment: For example if you have an iteration where the list comprehension is of size n, then for all other iterations, the list comprehension is of size 0 (this only happens when all entries in the array have the same value).

Comment: Gotcha, but if the list comprehension runs n times it would have O(n) and taking into account the first for loop it would give O(n+n)?

Comment: In part, but you would still have k comparisons even if you are not in the worst case scenario.